# How to issue a command from the command line of a process running on Linux

Tags: python, linux

Lets say I issue a command from the Linux command line. This will cause Linux to create a new Process and lets say that the Process expects to receive the command from the user.

For Example: I will run a python script test.py which will accept a command from the user.

$python test.py

TEST>addController(192.168.56.101)

Controller added

TEST>

The question I have is can I write a script which will go into the command line (TEST>) and issue a command? As far as I know if I write a script to run multiple commands it will wait for the first process to exit before running the next command.

Regards,

Vinay Pai B.H.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look into [expect](http://expect.sourceforge.net/). It's a tool that is designed to automate user interaction with commands that need it. The [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/expect) explains how to use it.

Seems like there is also [pexpect](http://www.noah.org/wiki/pexpect), a Python version of similar functionality.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the Python script is reading its commands from stdin, you can pass them in with a pipe or a redirection:

```
$ python test.py <<< 'addController(192.168.56.101)'

$ echo $'addController(192.168.56.101)\nfoo()\nbar()\nbaz()' | python test.py

$ python test.py <<EOF
addController(192.168.56.101)
foo()
bar()
baz()
EOF
```

Comment: Thank you so much but I forgot to mention that I wanted the entries to be read in real time. Can I maintain the PID and do a redirect to the PID? Im not sure if that will work.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind waiting for the calls to finish (one at a time) before returning control to your program, you can use the [subprocess](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) library.  If you want to start something running and not wait for it to finish, you can use the [`multiprocessing`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html) library.